# REST API PAYPAL Update Order C# - Malformed Body Error

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am running the following in an attempt to update the Amount entity in PayPal via C# REST API call using the returned Update link after Order successful CREATED status:

```
        using (client = new HttpClient())
        {

            //security token & apikey
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("content-type", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("PayPal-Request-Id", paypal_request_id.ToString());


            try
            {

                Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));
                (uri is the returned url I get back after ORDER creation: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/87Y78751VW96438##)

                PayPalUpdateOrderRequest.Root ppuor = new PayPalUpdateOrderRequest.Root();
                PayPalUpdateOrderRequest.Value ppuor_val = new PayPalUpdateOrderRequest.Value();
                ppuor_val.currency_code = "CAD";
                ppuor_val.value = newtotal.ToString();
                ppuor.op = "replace";
                ppuor.path = "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount";
                ppuor.value = ppuor_val;


                var method = "PATCH";
                var httpVerb = new HttpMethod(method);
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ppuor);
                var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = uri,
                    Content = content,
                    Method = httpVerb
                };


               HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

               var ss = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

               retVal = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  etc...
```

The JSON data sample that I am sending above:

{
"additional_properties": "xxxxxx",
"body": {
"op": "xxxxxx",
"path": "xxxxxx",
"value": {
"currency_code": "xxxxxx",
"value": "xxxxxx"
}
},
"header": {
"accept": "application/json",
"accept-encoding": "identity",
"akamai-x-forwarded-for-7": "xxxxxx",
"authorization": "xxxxx",
"client-auth": "xxxxx",
"client_info": "xxxxxx",
"content-length": "120",
"content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"correlation-id": "1d66e1179970f",
"edge-locator": "xxxxxx",
"edgeid": "xxxxxx",
"host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
"paypal-request-id": "0fa4cf63-84ff-4781-a5e3-e768b1503cb0",
"paypal-routing-metadata": "xxxxxx",
"pp_client_ssl_cipher": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
"pp_client_ssl_protocol": "TLSv1.2",
"pp_geo_loc": "CA",
"pp_remote_addr": "156.34.171.36",
"pp_vip": "173.0.93.165",
"user-agent": "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; SM-G960W Build/QP1A.190711.020)",
"x-forwarded-for": "10.96.34.199",
"x-forwarded-proto": "xxxxxx",
"x-paypal-correlation-id": "1d66e1179970f",
"x-pp-corrid": "1d66e1179970f",
"x-pp-idempotencyid": "1d66e1179970f_1673472611",
"x-pp-slingshot-targetapp": "apiplatformproxyserv",
"x-sigsci-agentresponse": "xxxxxx",
"x-sigsci-mac": "xxxxxx",
"x-sigsci-requestid": "xxxxxx",
"x-slr-orig-script_uri": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/87Y78751VW9643809"
},
"method": "PATCH"
}

Getting MALFORMED REQUEST Error on RESPONSE:
{
"additional_properties": "xxxxxx",
"body": {
"debug_id": "1d66e1179970f",
"details": [
{
"description": "The request JSON is not well formed.",
"field": "/",
"issue": "MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON",
"location": "body"
}
],
"links": [
{
"encType": "xxxxxx",
"href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON",
"rel": "information_link"
}
],
"message": "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",
"name": "INVALID_REQUEST"
},
"duration_time": "xxxxxx",
"header": {
"APPLICATION_ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
"BORDER-IP": "xxxxxx",
"CALLER_ACCT_NUM": "GAEWUQHX5X8ZU",
"Date": "Wed, 11 Jan 2023 21:30:12 GMT",
"PROCESSING-IP": "xxxxxx",
"SERVER_INFO": "xxxxxx",
"paypal-debug-id": "1d66e1179970f"
},
"status": 400
}

I have tried a bunch of possible ways to send in the update - got them from the postman order update multiple fields example.

The link for the paypal help page is not very helpful, I posted the logs above

Modified the code multiple times and retested.  I am sure it just a matter of the json object being sent in

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the forward-slash in the strings. [Look at the JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and you'll see STRING defined:  The flow diagram is telling you that "/" and all those others must be preceded by "\"; that is, you must escape the control characters.

Comment: Hi RadarBob! I will give that a shot.  I had a feeling about that when looking at another thread but was not sure.  Thanks for the advice, I will give it a go and update as soon as I do.  Cheers, joe